# How to track Javascript problems in my website when using Android 2.3?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm working on a web-based system developed in **HTML5** and **PHP** using jQuery.

It is actually meant to be used through a web browswer, but some simple functions would come in handy if people could do it through their phones.

On Android 4+ it works perfectly, but on Android 2.3 using the default browser, absolutely nothing works.

Not even the first simple function: `log in`. I just want to know how to track down the problem so I can study how to fix it.

While I'm here, I'm going to post my form and `.js` file:

```
 <form id="companyLogin" action="javascript:Welcome.company()">
        <section>
            <header>
                <h2>@{welcome.loginStaff}</h2>
            </header>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>@{welcome.email}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="btext" name="email_company" required></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>@{welcome.password}</td>
                    <td><input type="password" class="btext" name="password_company" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div>
                <a href="@@hinz@$home/company">@{welcome.register}</a>
                <input type="submit" class="bbutton bbuttonMid"
                       value="@{welcome.submit}">
            </div>
        </section>
    </form>
```

And here is my `.js` file:

```
var Welcome = {
    company : function() {
        var ajaxData = Nav.ajax.data('#companyLogin');
        ajaxData.type = 'company';
        Nav.ajax.submit('home/login', 'login', ajaxData, function(data) {
            Nav.redirect('user/panel');
        });
    },
    recover : {
        send : function(){
            var ajaxData = Nav.ajax.data('#passwordRecover');
            Nav.ajax.submit('home/login', 'recover', ajaxData, function(data) {

                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to debug thru http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html
or 
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/08/14/debugging-javascript-on-android-and-ios/

Comment: Adobe Edge Inspect could be a helpful tool for this.